# Two similar pieces of software using a shared database -- How to do it best?

Tags: sql-server, database, delphi, versioning

we make software for managing participants in grants given to non-profits. (for example, if your family needs food stamps, then that office must somehow track your family and report to the state)

Up until now we have been focused on one particularly complex grant. We are now wanting to expand to other grants. Our first goal was a fairly simplistic grant. The code for it was just piled onto the old application. Now we have decided the best course of action is to separate the two programs(because not all of our clients have both grants). This sounds easy in theory.

We can manage the code complexity brought about by this pretty easily with patches and SVNs merging functionality. The thing that is significantly harder is that their database is the same. The two grants share a few tables and a few procedures. But this is a rather large legacy database (more than 40 tables, 100s of stored procedures).

What exactly is the best way to keep these two databases separate, but still sharing their common elements? We are not concerned about conflicts between the two applications writing to the same DB(we have locks for that), but rather we're concerned about schema conflicts in development and updating our client's servers and managing the complexity.

We have a few options we've thought of:

1. Using Schemas (shared, grant1, grant2)
2. Using prefixed names

Answer (score 2):

The book [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) had a solution to this sort of thing. Sharing common data is fine, just move the extended data into a separate table, much like extending a class in OOP.

```
Persons Table
--------------------------
PersonID      LastName       FirstName

FoodStamps Table (From Application 1)
--------------------------
PersonID      FoodStampAllotment

HousingGrant Table (From Application 2)
--------------------------
PersonID      GrantAmount
```

You could add prefixes to the extended tables if you want.

This query will get me just people in the FoodStamps program:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
  JOIN FoodStamps
  ON FoodStamps.PersonID = Persons.PersonID
```